# Objective-c underline NSTextField Label on hover

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

So this question actually involves 2 questions.

- First, I have programmatically created about 5 NSTextField Labels and I was wondering how I could underline them when I hover a label, the corresponding label will underline? I have been stumped on this so I have no clue how to even go about doing it. I know most people are going to think I am crazy for even asking the next question, but I do have my reasons for doing it.
- Second, How can I attach a click to an NSTextField Label? I don't want to use a button because I don't want the background color to be visible when I click it, even if I hide the border, there is still a background color visible on click. I have looked around(stackoverflow.com and google) and nobody seems to have an answer to either of these questions. You will probably need the code of how I drew the NSTextField Labels so here you go.

  ```
  NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor lightGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
  NSAttributedString * trashText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Trash" attributes: attributes];
  [trashText drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 500)];
  ```

**UPDATE**

Added more objective-c.

**MainWindowController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MainWindowController : NSWindowController {
    @private

}
@end

@interface EmailContents : NSView {
    @private
}

@end

@interface SideBar : NSView {
    @private
}

@end

@interface ClickableTextField : NSTextField
@end
```

**MainWindowController.m**

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"
#import "NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.h"

int currentView = 1;

@implementation NSAttributedString (Hyperlink)
+(id)fakeHyperlinkFromString:(NSString*)inString withColor:(NSColor*)color {
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: inString];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);
    [attrString beginEditing];
    // make the text appear in color
    [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
    // make the text appear with an underline
    [attrString addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];
    [attrString endEditing];
    return [attrString autorelease];
}
@end

@implementation SideBar
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)HTMLContent {
    int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;
    if (currentView == 1) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:16], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        NSAttributedString * text_one=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"text_one" attributes: attributes];
        //[text_one setAttributedStringValue:[NSAttributedString fakeHyperlinkFromString:@"text_one" withColor:[NSColor whiteColor]]];
        [text_one drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 600)];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor darkGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        NSAttributedString * text_one=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"text_one" attributes: attributes];   
        [text_one drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 600)];
    }
    if (currentView == 2) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:16], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        NSAttributedString * text_two=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"text_two" attributes: attributes];
        [text_two drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 575)];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor darkGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        NSAttributedString * text_two=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"text_two" attributes: attributes];
        [text_two drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 575)];
    }
    ...
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably subclass the NSTextField to implement what you want. I did.

### 1. Underline

I made an extention function to the NSAttributedString (NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.m)

```
+(id)fakeHyperlinkFromString:(NSString*)inString withColor:(NSColor*)color {

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: inString];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);

    [attrString beginEditing];

    // make the text appear in color
    [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];

    // make the text appear with an underline
    [attrString addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];

    [attrString endEditing];

    return [attrString autorelease];
}
```

And then you can assign the title to the NSTextField (label) like this:

```
[myTextField setAttributedStringValue:[NSAttributedString fakeHyperlinkFromString:@"Hello world!" withColor:[NSColor blueColor]]];
```

### 2. Click on NSTextField -> send action

Here you can use delegate to performSelector on it.
Declare delegate in h-file of NSTextField subclass:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet id delegate;
```

with corresponding `@synthesize` in m-file.
Now you can connect (assign) delegate in IntefaceBuilder (xib-file).

After that you can implement mouseUp (or mouseDown) method of NSTextField subclass:

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    [super mouseUp:theEvent];

    // call delegate
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldWasClicked)] {

        [delegate performSelector:@selector(textFieldWasClicked) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

That worked for me. Now you try.

---

**UPDATE**

You should put `fakeHyperlinkFromString` to the **NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.m** as a category to the NSAttributedString.

**H-File:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSAttributedString (Hyperlink)

+(id)fakeHyperlinkFromString:(NSString*)inString withColor:(NSColor*)color;

@end
```

**M-File:**

```
#import "NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.h"

@implementation NSAttributedString (Hyperlink)

+(id)fakeHyperlinkFromString:(NSString*)inString withColor:(NSColor*)color {

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: inString];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);

    [attrString beginEditing];

    // make the text appear in color
    [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];

    // make the text appear with an underline
    [attrString addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];

    [attrString endEditing];

    return [attrString autorelease];
}

@end
```

And then just include this NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.h where you use `fakeHyperlinkFromString`.
It is usualy a controller (window controller).


In this controller you should have a pointer to your textField object (subclass if you created one). This can be done by declaring `@property` with `(assign)` and `IBOutlet`, synthesizing it and connecting in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: Thank you for giving a very complete answer. I do some questions, where do I put the `+(id)fakeHyperlinkFromString:(NSString*)inString withColor:(NSColor*)color {}`, as in what file do I put it in, the MainWindowController.h or MainWindowController.m? Also, what do I put where it says `myTextField`, the name of the textfield? Just so you know, I am kinda new to Objective-C and learning as I go along so can you explain subviews? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Read more about categories: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and incredibly thorough answer. One last question, the string is being made programmatically so how would I bind to the string if it is made in the NSDrawRect method.

Comment: You mean that string is in graphical form or it is contstructed in drawRect method? Did't get the question. More details, please.

Comment: The string is created in the drawRect method. How do I connect and synthesize to it if I am not using interface builder? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to "bind" to string. To have textField with underlined text, you have to assign the NSAttributedString with `[textField setAttributedStringValue]`, but you should do it once (not each time drawRect is called). It is hard to be more specific without seeing your code.

Comment: First - you better write `@implementation NSAttributedString (Hyperlink)` is separate file named **NSAttributedString+Hyperlink.m**. You did included the header file anyway, so use the advantages ;)

Comment: Second - you have a memory leak when do alloc/init and then leave the variable on it's own, allocating the memory again next time. You should assign it to a variable and release it when not needed or use autorelease method to tell Autorelease Pool to free the memory later.

Comment: Third - Creating the string in drawRect method is a bad design IMHO. Create 2 properties (or private class variables) named **text_one** and **text_two** and store the strings in them. Use actions or delegate calls to update the strings values/options (the same point where you can assign the attributedString to your TextField). And then let the drawRect draw the content that is stored at the moment.